Error while trying to add CAN_MONITOR permission for SQL warehouse usage terraform
I was trying to provide CAN_MONITOR Permission to SQL warehouses in Azure Databricks with the help of terraform but i was Getting error while trying to add CAN_MONITOR permission for SQL warehouse usage terraform

permission_level CAN_MONITOR is not supported with sql_endpoint_id objects

Can anyone help me with this?
I was following this documentation : https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databricks/databricks/latest/docs/resources/permissions#sql-warehouse-usage
